# How to clear all elements in a page with PHP?

Tags: php, html

Is there any way to clear all html elements in a php page?

For example I have 100 html elements in my page, is there anyway to remove them?

As we know with javascript we have `innerHTML` but in PHP what?

Comment: What do you mean by elements? HTML elements? What do you mean by clear?

Comment: Because your question is nonsense and impossible to answer

Comment: @MikeRedford No, that isn't how the site works. Voting is anonymous by design. Nobody owes you a comment.

Comment: Will you please relax? A down-vote is not the end of the world. It doesn't matter. Your question is still fundamentally unanswerable because you don't understand the technology you're asking about.

Answer (score 4):

> clear all html elements in a php page

That doesn't make sense. HTML elements only exist in the DOM after PHP has executed and sent an HTML document to the browser. Server-side, where PHP executes, there are no elements to remove.

If you're trying to manipulate the HTML you've already output, you need to capture it with output buffering (see [`ob_start`](https://www.php.net/ob_start), [`ob_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/ob_get_contents) and [`ob_end_clean`](https://www.php.net/ob_end_clean)) but if your goal is to "clear all html elements", presumably so you can output a different set of elements, you simply need to *not output anything* in the first case. If this sounds like what you're trying to accomplish, you need to look into simple conditional statements like `if`/`else`.

> as we know with javascript we have innerHTML but in php what ?

There is no PHP-equivalent because PHP doesn't have access to the client-side DOM. It is purely a server-side technology, and the output of your PHP script is the input to the browser. The DOM and its elements are generated long after your PHP script has executed. If you have an XHTML fragment in a string, and you want to parse/manipulate it, you can use [xpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

Answer (score 3):

If your question is "clear html elements in a php file", the answer is: `strip_tags()`.

`$string = '<p>hello</p>';`

`echo strip_tags($string);`

Comment: your question before edited : `Is there any way to clear all html elements in a php page ???`  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8632995/revisions ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
if(//why you want to clear the elements){ 
echo "<script language=\"javascript\">";
?>

//Append all elements in <div id="body">
var body = document.getElementById("body");
body.innerHTML ="";

<?php
echo "</script>";

#Output your new element
echo "New elements.";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should definitely work.

```
<?php
echo "<script>document.write('');</script>";
?>
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, but code execution stops immediately